# Users Export module hook

Tags: 7, users, importing-exporting

I'm using [Users Export](https://drupal.org/project/users_export) that provides a hook with no extra information.
I need somehow to explore the `$info` parameters in order to this extra fields

my code:

```
function display_my_users_loft_data_grids_info_alter(&$info) {
    var_dump($info);
}
```

But in that case the `var_dump` doesn't work.

Does someone know any example or documentation or help me to debug that?

Answer (score 1):

Get the [Devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel) module installed and use the `dpm()` function, e.g.

```
function display_my_users_loft_data_grids_info_alter(&$info) {
    dpm($info);
}
```

Then perform whatever action it would take to invoke that hook, and you'll see the `$info` variable exported to the messages area for easy browsing.

Comment: It doen't work, is there any way to check if something is invoked?

Comment: Well yeah, but the above method is it! Have a look through the code on the module for `module_invoke`, you should be able to see how the info array is built up there